# Attempting to subtract the values between two different Pandas Series based on corresponding indices

Tags: python, pandas, series

Here are the two series. They were generated after grouping a dataframe based on two column values, `patient_id` and `event_description`:

Series 1:

```
patient_id                                event_description     
A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-09-15
B                                             DiagnosisA          2013-01-01
C                                             DiagnosisA         2016-01-10
D                                             DiagnosisA          2015-01-02
```

Series 2:

```
patient_id                                 event_description     
A                                             DiagnosisB          2016-09-30
B                                             DiagnosisB          2013-01-04
D                                             DiagnosisB          2015-01-15
```

So I essentially Would like to find the difference in time between between each patient. For example for patient `A` it would return 15 days but for patient `C`, It could say `NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `groupby` included both `DiagnosisB` and `DiagnosisA`, you could `unstack` beforehand and subtract

```
# This should be what you have after groupby
s = pd.concat([s1, s2])

s

patient_id  event_description
A           DiagnosisA          2016-09-15
B           DiagnosisA          2013-01-01
C           DiagnosisA          2016-01-10
D           DiagnosisA          2015-01-02
A           DiagnosisB          2016-09-30
B           DiagnosisB          2013-01-04
D           DiagnosisB          2015-01-15
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then you can `unstack` and subtract

```
s.unstack().pipe(lambda d: d.DiagnosisB - d.DiagnosisA)

patient_id
A   15 days
B    3 days
C       NaT
D   13 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

**Not Recommended**
*But fun with `unstack` and `squeeze`*

```
s1.unstack().squeeze().rsub(s2.unstack().squeeze())

patient_id
A   15 days
B    3 days
C       NaT
D   13 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

**Also Not Recommended**
*But fun with `xs`*

```
s1.xs('DiagnosisA', level=1).rsub(s2.xs('DiagnosisB', level=1))

patient_id
A   15 days
B    3 days
C       NaT
D   13 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

**Final Non-Recommendation**
*Had to show `pd.IndexSlice`*
**Note:** Indices need to be fully lexsorted for this to work.

```
s1.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'DiagnosisA']].rsub(s2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'DiagnosisB']])

patient_id
A   15 days
B    3 days
C       NaT
D   13 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Still not that much familiar with pipes should learn more abt it, its cool. It feels like magic

Answer (score 3):

If the `event_description` column has no role to play here, I'd suggest just getting rid of it. Make a `reset_index` call and just subtract the resultants.

```
r1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
r2 = df2.reset_index(level=1, drop=1)

r = r2.sub(r1)

r
           time
patient_id        
A          15 days
B           3 days
C              NaT
D          13 days
```

Comment: wouldnt the output be zero?

Comment: @Bharathshetty If they're datetimes, the result will be a timedelta, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: r2 - r2 cancel each other haha :)

Comment: @Bharathshetty LOL Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reset_index`, we can also use `droplevel` i.e

```
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(1)
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel(1)

df2 - df1
```

Output :

```
           time
patient_id        
A          15 days
B           3 days
C              NaT
D          13 days
```